# Importing existing django project to PyCharm 3.4 professional

Tags: django, pycharm

I have the following file tree sturcture

```
beta
├── data
├── libs
└── wsgi
    ├── openshift
    └── static
```

which contains a django project. Django files are inside openshift under wsgi folder. I am trying to import it to Pycharm but It won't recognise the imports. I set content_root of my project the beta folder but still the same error. How can I successfully import an existing django project to a pycharm project?

Comment: Have you tried adding openshift as an additional content root. I use a mac so adding this would be under PyCharm -> preferences -> Project Structure, then click + Add Content Root and add the path to openshift. We have an odd project structure so we need to add additional content roots like this for PyCharm to recognise the imports.

Comment: yes I did thank you...I also had to enable Django for the project to have manage.py and setting's file set up. Thank you!